# How to display Facebook post in native iOS app?

Tags: ios, facebook, view, native, status

How do I display a Facebook post in a native View in an iOS App? Is there something like TweetKit for Twitter (https://dev.twitter.com/twitter-kit/ios/show-tweets)?

If not, how can I fetch the data for a Facebook post? Is this possible without logging in?

Answer (score 0):

Without login, you can't get any information regarding the facebook.
I think this link will help you
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/ios

Good luck

Comment: This seems to be only about sharing something to Facebook. I only need to display an available post in a native environment.